# Speculative Plate Techtonics - Resolving intersecting subductions

Tags: geology, plate-tectonics, tectonics

I'm working through Artifaxian's (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AzD_WVsEIRM) series on using gPlates to make tectonic history.  I've run into the place where I have two subduction ridges about to meet.  The bottom continent is moving up, the one at the top is moving down. Which one is likey to subduct?

I can imagine that the unified front of the bottom subduction could make it easier for it to take under the top subduction zone.  Likewise I could imagine that the sharp point could pierce the bottom one.

The ocean crust segments are the same age.

Thanks for any thoughts and ideas you share!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two continental plates meet, neither generally subduct -- you just get a big collision, in the way the Alps and the Himalayas are formed. That's because continental plates are relatively light, and neither wants to disappear into the mantle.

If a continental and an oceanic plate meet, the oceanic plate (being denser) generally loses the battle and subducts. If two oceanic plates meet, it's a toss-up.